# Procesado de input file en PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Buen día.
Quisiera saber como hacer que mi...

```
<input type="file" name="ent_reg">
```

Sea procesado en PHP, o sea subir el archivo a mi hosting y guardar la ruta en base de datos MySQL.

> La tabla en MySQL sería así
>
> Columnas 4
>
> Identificación, nombre completo, contraseña, y imagen de perfil.
>
> Donde "imagen de perfil" guarde la ruta donde se guardó el archivo subido a mi hosting, para así llamarlo cuando dicho usuario inicie sesión.

Quiero que el nombre del archivo se cambie, estoy trabajando para asignar una imagen de perfil para el usuario, o sea un avatar. Si el usuario que subió el archivo se llama "John Kalibur" entonces en los directorios de mi servidor esta de esta forma

> htdocs/usuarios/data/john68/archivo_john68.jpg

Cómo puedo hacer esto posible?
Gracias por el tiempo invertido en mí.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la parte de HTML, con ese input dentro de un form, el archivo ya sería envíado sin problemas.
Hacer la validación en cliente o en servidor, ya va a gusto de cada uno, pero en mi ejemplo, la realizaré en la parte de servidor.

```
<?php
$ruta_base   = "avatares/";
$archivo     = $ruta_base . basename( $_FILES["ent_reg"]["name"] );
$Ok          = 1;
$tipo_imagen = pathinfo( $archivo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );

//comprueba que es una imagen
if ( isset( $_POST["submit"] ) ) {
    $check = getimagesize( $_FILES["ent_reg"]["tmp_name"] );
    if ( $check !== false ) {
        echo "Es una imagen - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $Ok = 1;
    } else {
        echo "No es una imagen.";
        $Ok = 0;
    }
}

//comprueba si existe
if ( file_exists( $archivo ) ) {
    echo "El archivo ya existe.";
    $Ok = 0;
}

//valida la extensión
if ( $tipo_imagen != "jpg" && $tipo_imagen != "png" && $tipo_imagen != "jpeg" && $tipo_imagen != "gif" ) {
    echo "Solo aceptamos extensiones JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF.";
    $Ok = 0;
}

//Sube el archivo, si se ha recibido un archivo válido
if ( $Ok == 0 ) {
    echo "El archivo no ha sido subido, lo sentimos.";
} else {
    if ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["ent_reg"]["tmp_name"], $archivo ) ) {
        echo "El archivo " . basename( $_FILES["ent_reg"]["name"] ) . " ha sido subido.";
    } else {
        echo "Lo sentimos, ha habido un error subiendo el archivo.";
    }
}
```

Y a partir de aquí, solo tendrías que hacer un insert en la base de datos con la ruta que tienes guardada en la variable de $archivo.

Answer (score 1):

que tal no se si lo tengas en tu form pero tambien es importante que en tu form tengas este atributo **enctype="multipart/form-data"**    `<form id="UserPictureForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">` 
de lo contrario no me funcionaba saludos.